# Replacing integers in an array with Integers from another array

Tags: java, arrays, replace

I am struggling with this problem where I have to take (i/2)+1 numbers from one array and then insert them into that back of a second array.

e.g. 1st array = {2, 5, 3, 4, 8, 9}
     2nd array = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}

```
 what i want to achieve = {-1, -1, -1, 4, 3, 5, 2}
```

So I want to take the 1st number in the 1st array and insert it into the last position of the 2nd array replacing the -1 and so on and so forth

What I have so far is:

```
    for(int i = 2nd Array.length; i <2nd Array.length; i--){            
        int value = 1st Array[i];
        2nd Array[i]= 2nd Array[i].replace(i, value);
    }
```

for the moment i'm just trying to get it to insert one set of values into the array.
I have not attempted taking only (1st Array.length/2)+1 numbers from the array.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to do this?

Comment: Progress:
for(int i = 0; i <(1st array.length/2)+1; i++){
   2nd Array[i] = 1st array[i];
   
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 2nd Array.length / 2; i++) {
     int temp =2nd Array[i];
    2nd Array[i] = 2nd Array[2nd Array.length - 1 - i];
     2nd Array[2nd Array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
   }

This returns {-1, -1, -1 , 2, 5, 3, 4} so we have made progress. 

However it is still not quite there.

i want to achieve = {-1, -1, -1, 4, 3, 5, 2}

Comment: See the EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, use one index for each array, `i1` index for `array1` and `i2` for `array2`.
Assuming both arrays are already initialised:

```
int i2 = array2.length-1;
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < (array1.length/2+1) && i2 >=0 ; i1++) {
   array2[i2] = array1[i1];
   i2--;
}
```

Or you can put everything in the `for`:

```
    int[] array1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] array2 = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    for (int i1 = 0, i2 = array2.length-1; 
            i1 < (array1.length/2+1) && i2 >=0 ; 
            i1++, i2--) {
        array2[i2] = array1[i1];
    } 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

Output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

**EDIT**
If you want the otherway, just change the direction for index `i1`, e.g.

```
    for (int i1 = array1.length/2+1, i2 = array2.length-1; 
            i1 >= 0  && i2 >=0 ; 
            i1--, i2--) {
        array2[i2] = array1[i1];
    } 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

Output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: However. I need the output to be [-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: for (int i1 = 0, i2 = Heap.length/2; i1 < (Heap.length/2+1) && i2 >=0 ;i1++, i2++) {
    Heap[i2] = input[i1];
      }

Comment: Anyway, I added the solution for your new requirements

Comment: Thank you. Apologies I misworded the question but your help was still valid and very appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an problem in your "for" loop.

```
for(int i = 2nd Array.length; i <2nd Array.length; i--)
```

It will exit the loop because "i" starts from 2nd Array.length and it will not be less than 2nd Array.length.

Answer (score 0):

to start in the middle of the array, you should set the initial value for i as (length/2 + 1), since arrays indexes starts on 0, you can use array2.length/2

```
for(int i = array2.length/2; i < array2.length; i++)
   array1[i] = array2[i];
```